# Disable/remove pagination from react material-table

Tags: reactjs, material-table

Is there any way to disable/remove pagination from react material-table. Im using the material-table plugin for react and finding it very difficult to remove the pagination. Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 28, accepted):

you can add `paging: false` to your options:

```
<MaterialTable
        //other stuff...     
        options={{
          paging: false
        }}
      />
```

For a list with all props check here: https://material-table.com/#/docs/all-props